# Swift 3 DispatchQueue Initializer: How should the qos and target parameters be used?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to understand the qos and target parameters to a DispatchQueue's initializer. I have seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634586/target-parameter-in-dispatchqueue/) unaccepted answers regarding the target but I doubt their complete correctness.

I'll repeat the excerpt from the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452989-dispatch_set_target_queue) (I assume that the meaning of target has not changed in Swift 3):

"*A dispatch queue's priority is inherited from its target queue. Use the dispatch_get_global_queue function to obtain a suitable target queue of the desired priority. If you submit a block to a serial queue, and the serial queue’s target queue is a different serial queue, that block is not invoked concurrently with blocks submitted to the target queue or to any other queue with that same target queue.*"

Regarding the first, two sentences: If the priority is inherited from the target queue then what is the impact of the DispatchQueue initializer's qos parameter?

Regarding the third (fricking doozy of a) sentence: If I wanted to serialize the execution of my code with the submissions in the target queue then why not just submit my work to the target queue in the first place? Maybe so that I do not have to get in the back of the line?

Thank you for any and all assistance with understanding this.

Comment: "If the priority is inherited from the target queue then what is the impact of the DispatchQueue initializer's qos parameter?" ... The qos parameter is very useful because you often don't specify any target, but you want to specify the quality of service.

Comment: Regarding the third sentence, while they just told you that you could specify a target which is a global (concurrent) queue of the appropriate priority, they're just warning you that if you happened to use a serial queue as the target, it's going to be serial with respect to everything else for which it is a target. In answer to your question, there's little benefit, AFAIK, in creating a serial queue whose target is yet another serial queue.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your comments. What I am left with is: Why even fool with specifying a target? Leave it nil and use the qos.

Comment: Yep, I generally wouldn't worry about target queues...