# What is the correct use of internalSerialQueueName when creating a SerialDispatchQueueScheduler from an existing DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, rx-swift

When doing something like this:

```swift
import RxSwift 
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.services")
let scheduler = SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: queue, internalSerialQueueName: ???)
```

It wants me to provide an `internalSerialQueueName` value. I assume I would just use `queue.label` to keep it all consistent, but I have seen code examples where people just use `""` for the `internalSerialQueueName`.

So, what is the correct use of the value for `internalSerialQueueName`?

Answer (score 0):

If we check implementation of the init:

```swift
/**
 Constructs new `SerialDispatchQueueScheduler` named `internalSerialQueueName` that wraps `queue`.

 - parameter queue: Possibly concurrent dispatch queue used to perform work.
 - parameter internalSerialQueueName: Name of internal serial dispatch queue proxy.
 - parameter leeway: The amount of time, in nanoseconds, that the system will defer the timer.
 */
public convenience init(queue: DispatchQueue, internalSerialQueueName: String, leeway: DispatchTimeInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.nanoseconds(0)) {
    // Swift 3.0 IUO
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: internalSerialQueueName,
                                    attributes: [],
                                    target: queue)
    self.init(serialQueue: serialQueue, leeway: leeway)
}
```

You will see that:

- `internalSerialQueueName` used as name for queue scheduler running in
- `queue` parameter is used only as target for internal queue of scheduler

You can read more about target queues in [target parameter in DispatchQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634586/target-parameter-in-dispatchqueue)